# Prove that there exists $h \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $h \geq 0$ and $\int f \circ T = \int fh$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am studying for the qualifiers and am trying to solve the following question:

> Let $(X, \mu, \mathscr{M})$ be a finite measure space. Suppose $T: X \to X$ is measurable and $\mu(T^{-1}(E))=0$ whenever $E \in \mathscr{M}$ and $\mu(E)=0$. Prove that there exists $h \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $h \geq 0$ and $\int f \circ T \, \rm{d}\mu= \int fh \, \rm{d}\mu$ for all $f \in L^\infty (\mu)$.

I am not sure where to even start with this problem. Any advice on where to begin would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did the g come from?  Did you mean $\int fh d\mu$ ?

Comment: @BettyMock Thanks! There was a typo in there. I have changed it.

Answer (score 3):

The pullback measure satisfied the Radon-Nikodym condition.  Invoke the Radon-Nikodym theorem to get existence of the function.